# the programme doesn't want to accept the array with a variable lenth in the function in c++

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int read ()
{ 
    int num;
    cout << "enter a number \n";
    cin >> num;
    return num;
}
int arrayNum (int num)
{ 
    int array[num];
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= num - 1 ; i++)
    {
        cout <<"enter number "<< i+1 <<endl;
        cin>> array[i];
    }
    return array[num];
}
void SumArray (int array[])
{  int num;
  
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0 ; i <= num - 1 ; i++)
   {
      sum = sum + array[i];
   }
   cout << sum <<endl;
}
int main ()
{
SumArray (arrayNum (read()));
}
```

i have a problem with the array variable paramater in function SumArray , also it give me this massege :"initializing argument 1 of 'void SumArray(int*)'void SumArray (int array[])".
and this : " invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] SumArray (arrayNum (read()));"

Comment: `SumArray` takes an array of `int`. `arrayNum` returns a single `int`. You likely want to use `std::vector<int>` to move collections of `int` around.

Comment: That's normal. Variable Length Arrays are not a part of standard C++. Some compilers support them as an extension to the language. And you have a variety of other problems in your code. And your title question is not what the error message you include in your post is about.

Comment: Note: Arrays come from a much  simpler time when your CPU had the power of a Dorito and you'd wet yourself with glee over a K of RAM. As a result they are really simple and really dumb. Even if your compiler allows you to dynamically allocate one, you'll find it's impossible to return. Arrays always decay to pointers when passed to or from a function and returning a pointer to a local variable is pointless. The variable goes out of scope at the end of the function, so the pointer points to storage that's no longer assigned to the array and could be reused at any moment.

Answer (score 0):

In c++, a static array cannot be of variable size because the compiler creates the array at compile time. In order to have an array of variable size, you must use dynamic memory. For example, a pointer and create a dynamic array using the `new` keyword or a `std::vector`.

For example:

Here's how to do it with a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<int> CreateAndFillVector(int size)
{
   std::vector<int> vectorOfInts;
   for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
   {
      cout << "Enter Number " << i << ":";
      
      int newValue = 0;
      cin >> newValue;

      vectorOfInts.push_back(newValue);
   }

   return vectorOfInts;
}

int main()
{
  int size = 0;
  cout << "Enter vector size: ";
  cin >> size;
  std::vector<int> vecOfInts = CreateAndFillVector(size);

  // Do what you want with the vector
}
```

And here's how to do it with `new`:

```
int * CreateAndFillArray(int size)
{
   int * ptr = new int[size]
   for (int i = 0 ; i < size ; i++)
   {
      cout << "Enter Number " << i << ":";
      cin >> ptr[i];
   }

   return ptr;
}

int main()
{
  int size = 0;
  cout << "Enter array size: ";
  cin >> size;
  int * ptr = CreateAndFillArray(size);


  // Do what you want with array


  // Must delete once complete
  delete ptr[size];
}
```

The error `Initializing argument 1 of 'void SumArray(int*)'void SumArray (int array[])". and this : " invalid conversion from 'int' to 'int*' [-fpermissive] SumArray (arrayNum (read()));` means that you cannot convert an int to an int pointer. `arrayNum` is returning an `int`, not an `int[]` or an int array.

Comment: You should prefer `std::vector` or `std::unique_ptr`. In the last companies I've worked, naked `new` and `delete` are considered bad practice and won't pass code reviews.

Comment: Better, but I agree with Jabaa. Upsell the `vector` by demonstrating it first. Too many people copy and past the first example without exploring the second.

Comment: For me, I learned pointers first before I learned ```vector```. The OP seems to be needing to understand dynamic memory before understanding ```vector```. That's why I originally wrote it with ```new``` only. But I can understand the reason for upselling ```vector```